# Installing NPM and Maven packages in a dockerfile

Tags: node.js, maven, docker, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins which spawns a new docker container to run a job. Once the job completes the container is deleted.

Every time an mvn install is run, the maven dependencies are downloaded from the Maven Repository. Since a new docker container is spawned for every job, the maven dependencies are not stored locally and have to be downloaded every time.

The same is the case for our npm packages which are downloaded every time we run npm install.

I was hoping there would be a way to download all the dependent packages onto the docker image that is used to run Jenkins jobs. This would result in a one time download and not have to be downloaded every time.

Here's a dockerfile I tried to use, but it did not work for maven dependencies -

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -q -y install maven

USER jenkins
COPY pom.xml /tmp/pom.xml
RUN mvn dependency:resolve -f /tmp/pom.xml
```

Using the new image, the maven dependencies were still downloaded from the mvn repo and not from the local repo.
Something would also have to be done for npm packages, using the package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want some **data to persist** while using Docker containers, you should use **[volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)**. So, for Maven try to link container's `~/.m2` directory to some directory on host that will store all downloaded dependencies.

Comment: You can’t use volumes at build time.

Comment: Yes, that's true. One should define a volume to use while starting the container using `docker run`. This is all nicely described under the link I've attached above.